# Push a local variable onto the stack

Tags: pointers, assembly, stack, push

Lately I have been doing a lot of assembly programming to boost my skills, and I came to realize that it is possible to push a local variable onto the stack like this `pushl 8(%esp)` however, I got confused on  that part because it seems that instead of doing the operation in the following order:

`decrement stack pointer -> fetch value 8(%esp) -> put on stack`, it seems to do this instead

`fetch value 8(%esp) -> decrement stack pointer -> put on stack`, can someone conform this, as I don't want my future endeavors to be based off of a false assumption
This was done on the gcc compiler!
thanks!!

Comment: it was a long confusing program I got online, and this behavior seemed odd to me since when doing something like `pushl %eax` esp gets decremented first then the value is pushed. which led to believe that it followed the first behavior i mentioned. would you like me to post the entire code?

Comment: I did it by doing `pushl 8(%esp)` as I mentioned, if esp is decremented first then the value that would be pushed would be garbage (since the variable I want is in 8(%esp)) but if the value is fetched first, then the variable would be pushed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is x86 code, yes, it fetches the value, decrements the stack pointer, then puts the value on the stack top. Reference [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_269.html).